# Test to compare percentage/proportions between groups in R

Tags: r, statistics, comparison

I have cell type proportions for 7 different cells, which sum up to 100% for every person (it's an estimate of cell type composition).

An example is something like this:

```
data1 <- rbind(c(0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025), c(0.1, 0.15, 0.6, 0.0375, 0.0375, 0.0375, 0.0375))

data2 <- rbind(c(0.3, 0.25, 0.4, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02), c(0.25, 0.3, 0.4, 0.01, 0.001, 0.01, 0.029))
```

Where rows would correspond to persons and columns to the cell types. In this example we would have 2 data sets with 2 persons each.

In reality, I have 2 or 3 data sets with different number of persons (around 400 and around 100).

**I want to test, if the proportion of cell types is different *between the data sets*.**

How could I do this in R?

I've read other posts with somewhat related questions. One thing suggested was logistic regression, but isn't this problematic as the "predictors" (cell types) are **dependent**, as they sum up to 100%?

Comment: Do you have the original counts instead of the calculated proportions? If so, you should be able to use a number of different options depending on sample size and distribution. A good place to start would be `prop.test()`, fishers exact test, or chi-squared test.

Comment: Thanks @HarrySmith, but unfortunately I have only %. The algorithm directly estimates proportions, not counts.

Comment: Your variables are perfectly multicollinear, but you could solve this by simply removing one of them, say just regress on the first six cell types, and treat the seventh as implied (which it is)

Comment: Thx @AkselA but what would you suggest to test all together? Because I am not interested if one specific cell type differs, but rather if the overall proportion is different between the groups...

Comment: Do you know anything about the sample sizes these proportions are based on? The raw counts would have been more informative.

Comment: I have 3 data sets around n = 400, n = 100, n = 250. And I should mention that there are different persons in the data sets, it is not repeated measures.